# How do I fix "pyinstaller is not found as a command" error?

Tags: pyinstaller

I am trying to convert main.py into an executable. I have the pyinstaller files in this directory as well as main.py but it returns this error code

(journal) C:\Users\caleb\PycharmProjects\PythonProjects\journal>pyinstaller main.py
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Me to.My error:
'pyinstaller' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Then I uninstall Python then I download Python and click "Add python to path"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSTFb.png)

And it is work very good!
I can run pyinstaller and more!